# Backup Home Directory 15GB across multiple DVDs preferrably free

Tags: backup

I would like to backup my Ubuntu Home directory (~15 GB) across multiple DVD's (I do not have an external HDD) ... is there a free and GUI friendly way to do this?  I have read many posts but they all seem a bit old and I'm wondering the right solution. Thank you!

Comment: Questions:  Are the files expected to be larger than the media? Do you want these files use-able from the DVD? And why gui? "tar", "split" and a copy to dvd is all you need for a backup.

Comment: I only did it once (because I use external HDDs and another computer now) and used dkopp, it's pretty easy to use and supports full and incremental backups. Also itsplits the data for you so you don't have to manually put your data in chunks so they fit on a DVD.

Comment: I am very new to Linux and get confused easily ... I tried the dkopp and got stumped on mounting the USB DVD writer ... sorry to bother you Guru's about this .... It is not that the files are larger than the DVD it is my intention to backup the whole home directory without having to pick and choose which file(s) go where on the DVD's ... more help please?

Comment: Nowadays, DVDs are a terrible backup medium. You can'
t

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is to purchase an inexpensive external USB3 hard disk drive (1TB for ~$50), and just drag your home folder out to it. Not the best backup method, but it'll do what you ask. Cheers, AL

Comment: The best would be to buy said drive and let Déjà Dup handle the incremental backup process for you. :)